# If the derivative at a point say $x=$c does not exist, why is $f'(c)=0$?

Tags: calculus

$$f(x)=(x^3+3x^2)^{\frac 12}$$
For this particular function, when I let $f'(x)=0$, I will get $x=0$ or $x=-2$. However, when I differentiated using first principles as $x$ approaches $0$ taking the left limit gives me $-1.732\ldots$ and the right limit gives $1.732\ldots$ which implies that the derivative at $x=0$ does not exist. if that is the case, why did I get the $x=0$ as one of the solution when $f'(x)=0$?

Comment: "When I let $f'(x) = 0$, I will get $x = 0$ or $x = -2$". Are you sure? Do you really get $f'(0) = 0$? Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/7062) to format your posts here.

Comment: @Jus please edit your post to answer Alex's question.

Comment: You are right Alex, I just noticed that f'(0) is not equal to 0. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On autopilot we would take the derivative as usual:
$$ f'(x) = \frac{3x^2+6x}{2\sqrt{x^3+3x^2}}. $$
But now we have already assumed the derivative exists (for $x\geqslant -3$). So when we solve for $f'(x) = 0$ we have to solve $x^2+2x=0$ yielding the candidate solutions you obtained (although, dividing by zero should raise some concerns, already).

But does the derivative actually exist at $a=0$?
$$ \lim _{x\to a} \frac{\sqrt{x^3+3x^2} - \sqrt{a^3+3a^2}}{x-a} = \lim _{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x^3+3x^2}}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\mathrm{sgn}(x) \sqrt{x+3} \text{ does not exist.} $$
So $f'(0)$ has no meaning in the first place.